# Appium: Not able to click/find element after terminate and reactivate the app

Tags: flutter, automation, automated-tests, appium, native

I run automation tests with Appium version 1.22.3.
I am trying to terminate the app and activate it again.
When I switch back to flutter context, find/click element doesn't work.
Flutter driver version is 1.4.0.
Any suggestions ?

```
driver.switch_to.context("NATIVE_APP")
driver.terminate_app(bundle_id)
driver.activate_app(bundle_id)
driver.switch_to.context("FLUTTER")

driver.execute_script("flutter:waitFor", ff.by_text('some text'))
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution or a workaround to this?